# Twig: date format with localizeddate extension

Tags: datetime, twig, twig-extension

I have:

```
<div class="date">
{{ event.date|localizeddate('full', 'none', null, 'Europe/Moscow', 'd MMMM YYYY, EEEE') }}
</div>
```

Where `event.date = '2016-12-30'`, MySQL DATE string.

When date localized, output is `'30 December 2017, Friday'`. I don't understand, why year is changed to 2017? Why that happening?

Comment: What is the timezone of your server?

Comment: server timezone is +3 UTC

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in a recent project.

In the documentation it says Y stands for "year of "Week of Year""
and y is for the year.

http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Answer (score -1):

try using this:

```
{{ event.date|date("m/d/Y")|localizeddate('full', 'none', null, 'Europe/Moscow', 'd MMMM YYYY, EEEE') }}
```